# Reading and reversing string using getchar in C

Tags: c

New C coder here. I'm not certain why, but my program gets stuck in the first while loop and will not move on to the other code. Does anyone have any idea what's wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char str[20];
    char reverse[20];
    int c;
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;

    printf("Enter a string: ");
    i=0;
    j=0;

    while((i<20)&&((c=getchar())!='\n')){
        str[i] = c;
        i++;
    }

    k=i;

    while((j<k)&&(i>=0)){
        reverse[j]=str[i];
        j++;
        i--;
    }

    printf("\n");
    if(i==0){
        while(i<k){
            putchar(reverse[i]);
        }
    }else{
        printf("logic error");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: `while(j<k){
        reverse[j++]=str[--i];
    }`... `putchar(reverse[i++]);`

Comment: What is a length of the string? Is it more that 20 characters or do you have       '\n' to terminate the loop.

Comment: The string is whatever length, but the program should only read and reverse the first 20 characters. '\n' is the escape sequence for the 'enter' key, which indicates the end of input

Answer (score 2):

```
#include<stdio.h>

void reverse(void)
{
    char c;
    if((c = getchar()) != '\n'){ reverse(); }
    putchar(c);
    return;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("Enter a line of text below:n");
    reverse();
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code don't get stuck in the first `while`. It gets stuck here:

```
    while(i<k){
        putchar(reverse[i]);
    }
```

because you never change `i` or `k`, i.e. an endless loop.

Try this instead:

```
    while(i<k){
        putchar(reverse[i]);
        ++i;
    }
```

Another problem is that you reverse one character past the input as `i` has been incremented to index the "next free char" . Don't do that.

Instead of:

```
while((j<k)&&(i>=0)){ 
    reverse[j]=str[i];
    j++;
    i--;
}
```

try:

```
while(i>=0){
    reverse[j]=str[i-1];  // Notice the -1
    j++;
    i--;
}
++i;
```

Putting it all together, it will be:

```
int main(void){
    char str[20];
    char reverse[20];
    int c;
    int i;
    int j = 0;
    int k;

    printf("Enter a string: ");
    i=0;
    j=0;

    while((i<20)&&((c=getchar())!='\n')){
        str[i] = c;
        i++;
    }

    k=i;

    while(i >= 0){
        reverse[j]=str[i-1];         // Notice
        j++;
        i--;
    }
    ++i;                             // Notice

    printf("\n");

    if(i==0){   // This if-statement is nor really needed - just remove it
        while(i<k){
            putchar(reverse[i]);
            i++;                     // Notice
        }
    }else{
        printf("logic error");
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```